# Does increasing cache size of memory translate to higher I/O speeds?

Tags: google-play-store, cache

Hello Android Enthusiasts!

I recently came across this app [SD Booster](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.mehrmann.sdbooster&hl=en) on the Play Store that claims to increase I/O speeds. On installing it, it showed me that the default cache size for my device is 128KB and the optimal size is 512KB.

My question is, will increasing the cache size to 512KB actually increase I/O speeds? Also, can changing the system defaults cause any adverse effects?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See Wikipedia: [Disk buffer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disk_buffer). And of course, accessing RAM is faster than accessing storage.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have read the wiki page. Still not sure if I should increase it.

Comment: You'll always want to weight that against the size of available RAM, of course, plus the expected benefit. If you've got at least 1 GB RAM, I'd try it with 512 kB and see if you can really feel a difference. You don't need that for "cosmetical reasons" (i.e. just for some benchmark to show "more points").

Comment: I've got 1GB RAM on my device. I'll try and find if there is any difference with 512KB. Thanks again for the advice.

Comment: Anytime. You also can play a little with the sizes: if you e.g. see a benefit with 512 k, try again with 768 k (does it get even better?) and 384 k (is that sufficient already?) to figure the optimal value for you. And don't forget to keep us updated, once you figured :) Also remember: it's perfectly fine to [answer your own question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17845/etiquette-for-answering-your-own-question) here ;)

Answer (score 1):

I did some research on the topic and came up with the following chart. It seems that increasing the cache size does NOT always translate to higher I/O speeds.

`Test Device: Samsung Galaxy S-III i9300, 1.7GHz, 1GB RAM, CM 11 Custom Modded`

`Test Operation: 100MB Archive Read, Paste 100MB file to SD Card, Launch Time: Stack Exchange`

The chart displaying the results of the test is as follows.

[image: Chart displaying variance of I/O speeds with cache size.]

As seen in the chart, all the three test parameters were on their best with the stock (default) cache size of 128KB. Higher sizes gave equally good performance in reading speeds, but failed to perform in write and launch operations.

**Conclusion: The default cache size has been already optimised for maximum performance and need not be changed by the user for day-to-day functions.**

Comment: Just remember that test conclusions will be predicated on hardware specs. I found on one of my devices that setting it to 1024KB made it snappier, Gallery app would respond way faster, but on my other devices - that setting is just wrong. Also a given test will have varying results, depending on what else is opened/running in the background (services, tasks, other apps, networking, and etc.), so perform several tests under varying conditions (or at least your normal operations) to acquire the best setting. Let us know what type of results you get after testing again.

Comment: @HasH_BrowN Sure, I'll edit my answer after testing with a variety of Android devices. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Please provide a link to the chart you came up with, for others and also further reading. Thanks for the response. +1 for a good answer